# Is there a command to generate .cmo .cmx .cmi .mli together?

Tags: compilation, ocaml

I have a `.ml` file, I would like to generate its `.cmo`, `.cmx`, `.cmi` and `.mli` by as least commands as possible, could anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to generate all these files at once.

```
.mli :   ocamlc -i     x.ml > x.mli
.cmi :   ocamlc        x.mli
.cmo :   ocamlc -c     x.ml
.cmx :   ocamlopt -c   x.ml
```

If you can do without the `.mli` file, you can generate the `.cmi` and `.cmo` files together with `ocamlc -c`.  Otherwise I think you'll have to generate files one at a time.

Note that there is a `.o` file for every `.cmx` file; they work as a pair.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Makefile` to do all this for you. I have an example project template here that might help: https://github.com/snim2/ocaml-template

Say `make byte`, `make native` or `make docs` to generate the sort of output you're looking for.